# No print statement in Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
print("Finding the type of triangle.")
print()
print("Note: Side C should be the longest side")
print()
side1 = float(input("Enter the length of side A: "))
print()
side2 = float(input("Enter the length of side B: "))
print()
side3 = float(input("Enter the length of side C: "))
print()

if (side1 > side2 and side1 > side3): ##validating triangle check for side A
    if (side1 >= side2+side3):
        print ("Invalid input, not a triangle. \nSide A must be smaller then the sum of Side B + Side C.")
    print()
if (side2 > side1 and side2 > side3): ##validating triangle check for side B
    if (side2 >= side1+side3):
        print ("Invalid input, not a triangle. \nSide B must be smaller then the sum of Side A + Side C.")
    print()
if (side3 > side1 and side3 > side2): ##validating triangle check for side C
    if (side3 >= side1+side2):
        print ("Invalid input, not a triangle. \nSide C must be smaller then the sum of Side A + Side B.")
    print()

if (side1 != side2 and side1 != side3): ##scalene triangle check
    if (side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2):
        print ("It is a Acute Scalene triangle.")
        if (side1**2 + side2**2 == side3**2):
            print ("It is a Right Scalene triangle.")
            if (side1**2 + side2**2 < side3**2):
                print ("It is a Obtuse Scalene trianle.")

if (side1 == side2 or side1 == side3): ##isosceles triangle check 1
    if (side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2):
        print ("It is a Acute Isosceles triangle.")
        if (side1**2 + side2**2 == side3**2):
            print ("It is a Right Isosceles triangle.")
            if (side1**2 + side2**2 < side3**2):
                print ("It is a Obtuse Isosceles trianle.")

if (side2 == side1 or side2 == side3): ##isosceles triangle check 2
    if (side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2):
        print ("It is a Acute Isosceles triangle.")
    if (side1**2 + side2**2 == side3**2):
        print ("It is a Right Isosceles triangle.")
           if (side1**2 + side2**2 < side3**2):
               print ("It is a Obtuse Isosceles trianle.")

if (side1 == side2 and side1 == side3): ##equilateral triangle check
    print ("It is a Equilateral triangle.")
```

It's a simple program that is supposed to take the three sides inputted from the user, calculate the angle and then determine what type of triangle it is, then print the corresponding statement back to the user. However if the user inputs 3,5,7 or 5,7,9 there is no print statement whatsoever. Yet the formulas are all correct.

Comment: Did you step through all your `if` statements? For those two combinations you indeed never reach a `print()` statement (other than empty `print()`s). Clearly you still have issues!

Comment: Without having looked through the code in detail, I suspect reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) will be valuable here. **TL;DR** - don't use == to compare floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into the correctness of your formulas, you can easily test each of your `if` statements against your inputs.

For `side1 = 3`, `side2 = 5`, and `sid3 = 7`, you can see that:

- `side1 > side2 and side1 > side3` is false
- `side2 > side1 and side2 > side3` is false
- `side3 > side1 and side3 > side2` is true

  - `side3 >= side1+side2` is false

as expected; the triangle input is valid. Then follows:

- `side1 != side2 and side1 != side3` is true

  - `side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2` is false, because `9 + 25 > 49` is false.

    - This branch is then done; any thing nested below the `if` test is *ignored*.

- `side1 == side2 or side1 == side3` is false
- `side2 == side1 or side2 == side3` is false
- `side1 == side2 and side1 == side3` is false

As such nothing is ever printed.

As such, I think you got your *indentation* wrong; you are excluding tests here:

```
if (side1 != side2 and side1 != side3): ##scalene triangle check
    if (side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2):
        print ("It is a Acute Scalene triangle.")
        if (side1**2 + side2**2 == side3**2):
            print ("It is a Right Scalene triangle.")
            if (side1**2 + side2**2 < side3**2):
                print ("It is a Obtuse Scalene trianle.")
```

by indenting them below the `side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2` test. *Unindent* those:

```
if side1 != side2 and side1 != side3:  # scalene triangle check
    if side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2:
        print("It is a Acute Scalene triangle.")
    if side1**2 + side2**2 == side3**2:
        print("It is a Right Scalene triangle.")
    if side1**2 + side2**2 < side3**2:
        print("It is a Obtuse Scalene triangle.")
```

I removed the surplus parentheses around the tests and fixed a typo for you as well. Now the last test will actually run and print `It is a Obtuse Scalene triangle.`

The same applies to the other two isosceles triangle tests:

```
if side1 == side2 or side1 == side3:  # isosceles triangle check 1
    if side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2:
        print("It is a Acute Isosceles triangle.")
    if side1**2 + side2**2 == side3**2:
        print("It is a Right Isosceles triangle.")
    if side1**2 + side2**2 < side3**2:
        print("It is a Obtuse Isosceles triangle.")

if side2 == side1 or side2 == side3:  # isosceles triangle check 2
    if side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2:
        print("It is a Acute Isosceles triangle.")
    if side1**2 + side2**2 == side3**2:
        print("It is a Right Isosceles triangle.")
    if side1**2 + side2**2 < side3**2:
        print ("It is a Obtuse Isosceles triangle.")
```

You may want to see about reducing the repetition here however; put the test for the equilateral *first*, then determine the triangle type in an `else` branch:

```
if side1 == side2 == side3:  # equilateral triangle check
    print("It is a Equilateral triangle.")
else:
    if side1 != side2 != side3:  # scalene triangle
        type_ = 'Scalene'
    else:                        # isosceles
        type_ = 'Isosceles'
    if side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2:
        print("It is a Acute {} triangle.".format(type_))
    elif side1**2 + side2**2 < side3**2:
        print("It is a Obtuse {} triangle.".format(type_))
    else:
        print("It is a Right {} triangle.".format(type_))
```

This covers all equilateral, scalene and isosceles triangle tests in one place, avoiding repeating the tests and messages for each.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is incorrect, e.g. for `3, 4, 5` Your scalene check fails the first test and all the others are not evaluated because they are indented:

```
if (side1 != side2 and side1 != side3): ##scalene triangle check
    if (side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2):
        print ("It is a Acute Scalene triangle.")
    if (side1**2 + side2**2 == side3**2):
        print ("It is a Right Scalene triangle.")
    if (side1**2 + side2**2 < side3**2):
        print ("It is a Obtuse Scalene trianle.")
```

You have similar issues with other tests.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the nested if statements. Right now the checks for right and obtuse scalene only if it's already acute. This seems to fix it:

```
if (side1 != side2 and side1 != side3): ##scalene triangle check
    if (side1**2 + side2**2 > side3**2):
         print ("It is a Acute Scalene triangle.")
    elif (side1**2 + side2**2 == side3**2):
        print ("It is a Right Scalene triangle.")
    elif (side1**2 + side2**2 < side3**2):
        print ("It is a Obtuse Scalene trianle.")
```

Note that it's generally better practice to use elif if you only want one if statement to trigger.